# How to solve a conflicting types error in c?

Tags: c, getline

I am getting an error for conflicting types in the function getline.  I am consistent in the variable and function types in both function declaration statements, so I do not know what the problem is.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int getline(char line[]);

int main()
{
   char line[100];
   int len;
   while ((len = getline(line)) > 0)
       printf("%d\n", len);
}

int getline(char line[])
{
   int i, c;
   for (i = 0; (c = getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        line[i] = c;
   if (c == '\n'){
        line[i] = c;
        ++i;
   }
   line[i] = '\0';
   return(i);
}
```

Comment: [`getline()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) is already a standard library function..why you have to use the same name?

Comment: `How to solve a conflicting types error in c?` Change the type name.

Comment: Did the compiler tell you where the function was initially declared with different types? If that was not your own declaration, that's a good hint that you are re-using existing identifiers and should change the name.

Comment: @SouravGhosh `getline` is rather a non-standard library function.

Comment: @Lundin Right, I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code compiles just fine with a conforming compiler.

The problem is that your compiler is set as a non-conforming compiler (it follows POSIX but not C). So you get a namespace collision between non-standard function `getline` that POSIX places in stdio.h.

With compilers like gcc you can block non-standard extensions from appearing in standard headers, by compiling with `gcc -std=c11`. By default gcc runs `-std=gnu11` though, which follows POSIX but not the C standard.

If you are a beginner learning C, always compile with `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: I will add those options from now on, as I am new to C!  Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 5):

It seems your compiler is configured to use the POSIX standard, and in POSIX environment, [`getline()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) is already prototyped in `stdio.h` as

```
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
```

which conflicts with your declaration / definition.

Use a different function name (ex: `my_getline()` or similar).

Comment: I had no idea that "getline" was already a function in POSIX.  I changed the name and it fixed everything.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can change getline function name to fetchline, and everything would work as expected. Kudos though to Lundin for the thorough explanation.